# Java - Number of array accesses in a[i] = a[i-1];

Tags: java, arrays

I know this is a stupidly simple question: how many array accesses are performed when the expression

```
a[i] = a[i-1]
```

is evaluated? I'd appreciate a stupidly simple answer nonetheless.

Comment: Where's the question? :)

Comment: @kocko It's in the title :)

Comment: 1) read from `a[i-1]`. 2) write to `a[i]`. There will be range and type checks along the way, but these are mostly implementation dependant - [JLS §10.3 and §10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) requires that `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and `ArrayStoreException` be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Two or One or None

Explanation: First, you never define `i` or show the code where you initialize any of the variables. Therefore if everything was intialized properly and `i` and i-1 were within the boundaries of the array then it would access two locations. `i` could be out of bounds to begin with or `i-1` could be out of bounds resulting in a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or a `NullPointerException` if you never initialized your array or `i`variable.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Two.

Explanation:
First, your piece of code will access the array to read the value at location `i-1`. Secondly, it'll write that value to location `i`.

Comment: This isn't very clear, what is a `value` in this context? What happens in the case of a primitive array? What happens in the case of reference types?